# How to reset scroll position on single page pagination

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I try to fix scroll location.
When clicking on another pagination, scroll location does not be reset.

Front : React
css framework : semantic-ui-react

```
  Paragraph = () => (
    <p style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap', wordBreak: 'break-all'}}>
      {[this.state.article.content].join('')}
    </p>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <Container text style={{marginTop: '3em'}}>
        <Header as="h1">{this.state.article.title}</Header>
        <this.Paragraph />
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <FixedMenuLayout />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={List} />
          <Redirect to="/" />;
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The full source code is here:
https://github.com/jpskgc/article/blob/master/client/src/components/List.tsx

I expect the scroll is reset when clicking another number in pagination component.
But the actual is not.
Plese take a look below picture.
[image]

After clicking "2" on pagination, I want the scroll is reset like below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` to your `setState` callback:

```
async btnClick(
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>,
    data: PaginationProps
  ) {
    //...

    this.setState({
      articleDatas: this.state.articles.slice(this.state.begin, this.state.end),
    },
    () => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
  }
```

Also note that your `await this.setState` won't work as you think. `setState` doesn't return a Promise. If you really want to have async `setState`, you can make own helper:

```
setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(state, resolve)
    });
}
```

[Source](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802).